# what is the use of stringsByAppendingPaths

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"/tmp/1.txt" ,@"/tmp/2.txt", nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[result stringsByAppendingPaths:array]];
        NSLog(@"%@", array2);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

The argument we provide to stringsByAppendingPaths: is an array and so is the return type. So what is the use of this NSString method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're appending empty string (`result`), so it doesn't make much sense. But if your receiver contains say `/tmp` and the array contains `1.txt` and `2.txt`, getting the array `/tmp/1.txt` and `/tmp/2.txt` makes sense.